# How can cells in a table column be displayed based on a value stored in local/session storage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, checkbox

I have a table where you can check a checkbox, and another column *Quantity #*, which contains jQuery UI widgets. If the checkbox is unchecked, then the corresponding cell in the quantity column is hidden.

I can navigate throughout the page using a home button and search functions so if I come back to an originally checked row, *then the cell in the _Quantity #_ column is no longer visible even though the checkbox in the row is still checked.*

**I want to use session storage to be able to keep the *Quantity #* column and cells visible throughout the session until the page is closed, but only if the row is checked.** I was able to use session storage to keep the checkboxes checked, but am having a problem with getting the *Quantity #* column to remain visible as long as the checkbox is checked for that row.

How can this be achieved?

JavaScript for the session storage for the checkbox:

```
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        // Iterate over the checkboxes and set their "check" values based on the session data
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.prop('checked', sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] === 'true');
    });

    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
        // save the individual checkbox in the session inside the `change` event, 
        // using the checkbox "id" attribute
        var $el = $(this);
        sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] = $el.is(':checked');
    });
});
```

JavaScript for the showing the table column/cell:

```
$(function () {
    $(".check").change(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
    console.log($('input.check').is(':checked'));
    var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity').data('quantity');
        console.log(quantity);

  if($('input.check').is(':checked'))
    $(this).closest('table').find('th.num').toggle(true);
    else
    $(this).closest('table').find('th.num').toggle(false);



    $(this).closest("tr").find(".spinner" ).spinner({
      spin: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( ui.value > quantity ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", quantity );
          return false;
        } else if ( ui.value <= 1 ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", 1 );
          return false;
        }

        var test = ui.value;
        sessionStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(test));
        var testtrue = sessionStorage.getItem("test");
        console.log(JSON.parse(testtrue));

      }
    });
  });
  });
```

HTML/PHP for table:

```
<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" id="checkid-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
            <td class="loc ui-widget-content"><input type="hidden"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][rp-code]" class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][sku]" class="sku ui-widget-content" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][special-id]" class="special-id ui-widget-content" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][description]" class="description ui-widget-content" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][quantity]" class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][unit]" class="unit ui-widget-content" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][quant]" style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" id="spin-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to alter the initial code that checks the session data on page load. When setting the *checked* property, if that value is true, show the corresponding cell for quantity in that row. Additionally, initialize a variable (e.g. `var showQuantityHeader` in the example below) and set it to `true` whenever a checkbox is checked. After iterating over the checkboxes, show that column header if that variable has been true.

```
var showQuantityHeader = false;
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
    // Iterate over the checkboxes and set their "check" values based on the session data
    var $el = $(this);
    //console.log('element id: ',$el.prop('id'),' sessionStorage[id]: ',sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')]);
    $el.prop('checked', sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] === 'true');
    if ($el.prop('checked')) {          
        //show the quantity cell in the column under header with class num
        $el.closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
        showQuantityHeader = true;
    }
});
```

For a demonstration of this, see [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b2mt-qf8r).

#### Update:

In comments, you mentioned "*is the plain textbox and the "spinner" feature with the up/down arrows is not there anymore*". In order to have the *spinner* ui elements created, the same code is necessary as in the click handlers (i.e. calling `$(this).closest("tr").find(".spinner" ).spinner({...})`).

A simple technique for this is to abstract that code for setting up the spinner based on the quantity into a function, e.g.

```
function setupSpinner(checkbox) {
    var quantity = $(checkbox).closest('tr').find('td.quantity').data('quantity');
    $(checkbox).closest("tr").find(".spinner" ).spinner({
      spin: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( ui.value > quantity ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", quantity );
          return false;
        } else if ( ui.value <= 1 ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", 1 );
          return false;
        }
      }
    });        
}
```

Then call that function when:

- iterating over checkboxes and setting the *checked* property based on the session storage value

  ```
  if ($el.prop('checked')) {          
      //show the quantity cell in the column under header with class num
      $el.closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
      showQuantityHeader = true;
      setupSpinner(this);
  }
  ```
- in the click handler:

  ```
  $(".check").change(function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
      setupSpinner(this);
  ```

See a demonstration of this in [this updated phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wd3m-sxqw).

#### Update II

Per your latest comment about persisting the values, I have updated the [demonstration phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ki8w-3nuh).

When setting the value, it sets the value at a key using the checkbox id:

```
var test = ui.value;
sessionStorage.setItem('value_'+$(checkbox).prop('id'), JSON.stringify(test));
```

Then when initializing the page and showing the spinners, it checks for a value in the sessionStorage:

```
var quantity = sessionStorage['value_'+$el.prop('id')];
if (quantity) {
    $el.closest("tr").find(".spinner" ).spinner( "value", quantity );
}
```

I will leave any other code changes as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: This works pretty well...the only problem I have now is when I navigate away and then back again to a checked row, all there is, is the plain textbox and the "spinner" feature with the up/down arrows is not there anymore

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to keep the spinner feature with up/down arrows and keep any value that may have been entered in the spinner already?

Comment: This works great! I just need to keep the set value inside the "spinner" when I navigate away from the page and come back to it. Would you be able to add that into your answer? Thank you very much, you have been very helpful!

Comment: Okay I have provided a second update. Any other code changes will be left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help!